# How to seperately label edge.label.position for parameter estimates and covariances

Tags: semplot

I am trying to seperately position the edge labels for the parameter estimates and the covariances.  For the parameter estimates I would like them at .1 and for the covariances and disturbances I would like them at .5, but I only know how to change them through the edge.label.position argument.

```
semPaths(fit,"std", layout = "tree3", 
 whatLabels = "std", edge.label.cex=.9, curvePivot = TRUE,
 residuals = TRUE, rotation = 2, sizeMan = 16, sizeMan2 = 6,
 sizeInt = 8, exoVar = FALSE, exoCov = FALSE, 
 nodeLabels = c("Social","Intrapersonal", "Distress  
 Tolerance","Intrusion","Avoidance","NACM","Arousal",
"BPD Symptoms"), edge.label.position = .5, 
label.cex = .8, label.scale = FALSE)
```

I expect the parameter estimates to be on the left side of the structural paths near the manifest variables and the parameter estimates to be in the middle of the paths for the covariance and disturbance.